# How to apply filters to a gridview( like applying filters to excel sheet)

Tags: gridview, c#-2.0

Hi I am doing an application, where I am populating the grid from database by passing different parameters to the stored procedure and getting data to a datatable and binding it to the grid view.Now I need to have filters applied to the grid so that it should just work like the filters applied to a excel sheet.

Can I have some piece of code for applying filters to the gridview with out changing the design of the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using DataTables, have a look at DataViews, available through setting DataTable.DefaultView

Comment: Firstly Thnaks for the response ! but the thing is here the columns are added to the grid dynamically and i need to have filters on every coloumn of the grid

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents, but you can specify a filter expression as the first parameter of DataTable.Select().

I don't know how that goes for you, but it could work out.